# EM Theory applied to reflection&refraction

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, reflection, refraction

I am going through a book "Optics" by E. Hecht, and, since I already do not remember some EM theory concepts, I am having troubles understanding the following paragraph:

> The laws of Electromagnetic Theory lead to certain requiremenets that must be met by the fields, and they are referred to as the boundary conditions. Specifically, one of these is that the component of the electric field **E** that is tangent to the interface must be continuous across it. In other words, the total tangential component of **E** on one side of the surface must be equal that on the other. [...] Hence, $u_n\times E_i + u_n \times E_r = u_n \times E_t $.

In the last formula all quantities are vectors.

So, I understand that $u_n$ is a vector perpendicular to the interface and pointing from the first to the second medium.

But:

1. How does **E** look on the picture like this? What is the direction of it?
2. How exactly the formula follows from the boundary condition? I suppose, I will understand the answer to this myself, if I get the question 1. correctly. But any explanation still would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your second question, but $\vec{E}$ is perpendicular to the ray in the picture. Note that this does not uniquely fix $\vec{E}$'s direction, as there are many ways to be perpendicular to a line in three dimensions; the particular direction in which it is perpendicular to the ray is defined as the polarization of the light.

Comment: You may want to take a look at Griffith's electrodynamics book; It has a very clear derivation of the boundary conditions and the reflection and refraction laws from them.

Comment: What I meant by the second question: I don't understand the meaning of $u_n\times E$ sum. Ok, if I look at the quote again, I see that it *should* be the total tangential component of **E**. But I fail to see it from $u_n\times E$ itself, and I don't understand where the vector product would actually be directed.

Comment: This question has a [relevant diagram](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/251823/why-dont-em-fields-change-orientation-after-hitting-a-surface) showing the fields.